# UIView Fill color

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, fill, drawrect

I have added a `UIView` to the nib file. I want to fill that `UIView` with a color in `drawRect` method. How can i do this?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [frame](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame) property of the UIView to draw your rectangle. Just pass it to the [CGContextFillRect](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html) function (having set the context fill color).

> Paints the area contained within the provided rectangle, using the fill color in the current graphics state.

So the code in drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext ();

    // The color to fill the rectangle (in this case black)
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    // draw the filled rectangle
    CGContextFillRect (context, self.bounds);
}
```

Comment: how to use frame property to draw rectangle?

Comment: @Priya the frame property is a CGRect (the rectangle for the view). This is the parameter you pass to CGContextFillRect. The code I listed will do what you are after.

Comment: Use self.bounds in CGContextFillRect. To round corners: self.layer.cornerRadius = self.height / 2; self.clipsToBounds = YES

Answer (score 3):

Why not just set backgroundColor to be the color fill you desire?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you really need to use `drawRect:` :

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting background colour in table view cell's sub view lead to invisibility of that view due the fact that on editing style enabled, selecting a cell makes all background view colour change